# calculate angle of line with negative slope

Tags: angle, slope

I want to use the formula
$$
tan(\alpha)=m
$$
for negative slopes but always get negative degrees. For instance, say the slope of a line $g$ is $-1$. Using the formula above (arctan$(-1)=\alpha$), I get $-45$ degrees instead of $135$ degrees.
Why exactly does this formula not returning correct angles for negative slopes?

Comment: It all depends on how you define $\arctan$. It is usually defined as the inverse function of the restriction of $\tan$ on $\left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula: $\alpha=\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}m,&m\ge0\\\pi+\tan^{-1}m,&m<0\end{cases}$